# Utility to enable "Always On Top" mode for any window in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, window-manager, windows-8

I'm looking for an application which will allow me to pin any arbitrary window running in Desktop mode in Windows 8.1 to the top, meaning it'll always be above the window I'm actively using.

Similar functionality exists in some video playing applications under the name "Always On Top". If I was on my Mac I'd use the program [Afloat](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/) which not only lets me pin but force semi-transparency onto any window, which would be neat if the Windows application did too but is not required.

Preferably, the application would be a mostly-hidden one running in the task bar which would set up a keyboard shortcut for me to hit when interacting with a window to keep it always on top.

Comment: [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) includes this feature, but I have no idea whether it works on Windows 8. Googling suggests that the basic functionality works, but I don't know about the specific feature you need.

Comment: I don't know how it stacks up on recent Win versions, but back in the day (over a decade ago before I switched to Linux) I used to use a program called Stiletto that was pure genius for tweaking the Windows environment. I see it is still alive under the name [PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/). I would handle this case and more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have had great success with [Always on Top](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/keep-window-always-on-top/5213/) under Windows 7, and it looks like it's still working perfectly under Windows 8.

It runs in the system tray, uses a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut, and is <200KB in size. It's also free.

If you're unsure about running strange code off somewhat strange websites, you can achieve the exact same result with an AutoHotKey script:

```
^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

Give this a go, I'm sure it will work wonders for you.

Comment: This is *perfect*, the only thing I wish it did was put a symbol on the pinned window to show that it's pinned, but this fixes my biggest frustration.

Answer (score 4):

If you want some visual indication that window is "alway on top", you can do it using AutoHotKey as mentioned in post before by Michael Frank. 
Just add one line to his script. It will make window border thin, so you can easily recognize "always on top" window.

```
^SPACE::  
Winset, Alwaysontop, , A  ; Window always on top
WinSet, Style, ^0x800000, A  ; Toggle the active window's thin-line border (WS_BORDER).
Return
```

Comment: The question was not how to *identify* a "sticky window", but how to *make* it sticky. So I'm afraid your answer doesn't really match the question.

Comment: Yes, but Kasra Rahjerdi (OP) wish, he can identify "always on top" window as well.

Comment: I didn't see that in the question – but a second check revealed it mentioned in a comment on [another answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1416/185), so you're right: He could combine both to have all he wants. My apologies for missing that!